# ExtJS 4.2: Ext.grid.feature.Summary error on store initialization

Tags: grid, extjs4, summary

I am testing ExtJS 4.2 (4.2.1) with my existing code, and it mostly works, except for one serious problem: when my page loads, I get a JS error:

```
Ext.fly(div).down(me.getNodeContainerSelector(), true) is null
```

It happens in:

- ext-all-debug.js l.105020 - createRowElement of Ext.view.Table
- called from ext-all-debug.js l.112748 - onStoreUpdate of Ext.grid.feature.Summary)

The call stack is too long to put here, but it happens after a 'sort' event is fired on the grid, which is empty at this point (it is populated later). The sort happens as the grid constructor calls initState(), trying to apply a saved state (the grid is stateful).

I tried to remove the saved state data, which helped the process go one step further: the grid was drawn but then it started loading and got stuck again in onStoreUpdate(), in the same manner.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue after upgrading to 4.2.1 from 4.1.2a. Changed how I defined features and plugins on the grid. Now using ptype and ftype. Seemed to solve it.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately changing my code to use ftype and ptype did not solve this problem for me.

Comment: The same situation for my code - changing features definition helped!